# How to get MFA pattern using regex in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, regex-group, nsregularexpression

I am using the regex `((.*)?:)?(.*)\\/([0-9]+|[n])?` to match pattern of type `module:function/arity`, where `arity` can be any number >= `0` or the string `n`.

Success cases should match:

```
foo:bar/1
bar/1
foo:bar/0
foo:bar/n
bar/n
```

This seems to work fine at https://regex101.com/r/AtI5Nw/3, but using the following code, I am getting only one match group for `"mod:func/1"`.

```
+ (NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult *> *)matchesInString:(NSString *)string withExpression:(NSRegularExpression *)pattern {
    return [pattern matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
}
```

[image: mfa]

I tried with `"mod:func/1"` string and I am getting only one match. How to get all matching groups as in the screenshot? I want to get the `module`, `function` and `arity` parts from the string.

Comment: You get one match, because it's a match for your whole pattern, you get the "full match" of your screenshot. Iterate it, and then check the `numberOfRanges` property of the `NSTextCheckingResult`. You can also use `rangeAtIndex:` of it if you want to find the subranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've done this, but...

`matchesInString:...` returns an array of `NSTextCheckingResult` objects. Each object represents a single match of the *entire* regex within the string.

Each `NSTextCheckingResult` object encapsulates a number of "ranges" (see `numberOfRanges` property). You then use `rangeAtIndex:` to extract the range of each group within that match instance.

If each target is in a separate string, you don't need `matchesInString:...`, simply use `firstMatchInString:...` to obtain the one, and only, `NSTextCheckingResult` for your string. You can then extract each group by getting its range, then return to the original string to extract the text of that component.